# Sql query same column count?

Tags: sql

I am trying to figure out how to write a query that counts values across multiple columns

```
Uniform  size
-------   ---
Shirts     34
Shirts     36
Trouser    30
Shirts     34
Trouser    30
Trouser    32
Shoe        8
Shirts     34
Shoe        9
Saree       6
```

can we make this like

```
  Uniform  Size  cont
  -------  ----  -----
  Shirts   34     3
  Shirts   36     1
  Trouser  30     2
  Trouer   32     1
  shoe     8      1
  shoe     6      1
  saree    6      1
```

Please help me

Comment: A classical group by ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select uniform, size, count(uniform) from thetable group by uniform, size
```

Comment: i will try and inform you Mr. Pascalz

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Pascalz it is working fine.